# Getting the solver type and step size (for fixed step solvers)

Tags: matlab, simulink

we are trying to integrate a simulation model into Simulink as a block. We have a custom continuous block which loads an m file that contains the functions Derivatives, Outputs etc.

My question is: is there a way to find out which solver is used currently and with which parameters? Our model won't be able to support variable time solvers and I would like to give a warning. Similarly, the model requires the fixed step time for initialization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the time step: you can put a variable (eg `Ts`) as timestep in the configuration, you only need to set it during initialization (eg in the init callback) and can use it again later on in other blocks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the current solver name using

```
get_param('modelName', 'SolverName');
```

Some of the other common solver parameters are

```
AbsTol
FixedStep
InitialStep
ZcThreshold
ExtrapolationOrder
MaxStep
MinStep
RelTol
SolverMode
```

You can find other parameters you may wish to query by opening the *.mdl* file in your favorite text editor and digging through it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your use case correctly, you are trying to determine the type of solver (and other solver params) for the top-level simulink system containing your block.

I think the following should give you what you want:

```
get_param(bdroot, 'SolverType');  % //Returns 'Variable-step' or 'Fixed-step'
get_param(bdroot, 'FixedStep');   % //Returns the fixed step size
```

Notice that for purposes of generality/reusability, this uses [bdroot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/bdroot.html) to identify the top-level system (rather than explicitly specifying the name of this system).

If you want to find out more about other model parameters that you can get/set, I would check out this [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/f23-7515.html).

Additionally, I'm interested to know why it is that your model doesn't support a variable-step solver?